# How to make Layout Flow Horizontally

Tags: android

[image]

How can I have a layout flow like this horizontally, I have tried using Viewpager by splitting the child text and showing each in each view pager but I don't know when the content have gotten to the end of the screen. The whole thing looks hacky. Is there an off the shelf implementation like this in android?

Comment: can you show us what have you tried in code?

Comment: At First glance this looks like a `ViewPager` implentation with padding and page margin . What have you tried ?

Comment: The issue with `ViewPager` is I have to supply a `List`. I only have long text I want to display. With `ViewPager`, I split the text into parts and show in each viewpager but mostimes they don't get to the end of the screen before it continues on the next

Answer (score 0):

Try to used recycler view in any fragment or activity.

First create custom adapter like below code..

```
public class RecyclerViewAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdpater.ItemViewHolder> {
List<String> mStringList = new ArrayList<>();// hear you can pass any pojo class object.
Context mContext;
public RecyclerViewAdpater(List<String> mStringList, Context mContext) {
    this.mStringList = mStringList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    final String str=mStringList.get(position); //  here your boject
    holder.textView.setText(str);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mStringList.size();
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

}

after that define recycler view into xml. 
this below code used in activity or fragment.
adpter pass your text message.

```
   final RecyclerViewAdpater adpater=new RecyclerViewAdpater(yourtextList,this);
    mRvData=findViewById(R.id.rvData);
    mRvData.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL,false));
    mRvData.setAdapter(adpater);
```

Horizotal way used..

```
  mRvData.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL,false)); // you can apply vertical default is vertical
```

more information refer this link.
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: I'm not trying to display a List. It's a single long text that I want it to move on to the next horizontal page when it hits bottom of the screen.